# Silo S01E09 - Who caused the cameras to go dark?

Tags: silo

In Silo season 1 episode 9, after Sim's wife warned Jules to get out from Sim's home, the screens in the control room started to go dark. This aided in Jules' escape. Who hacked the cameras? The hacker character only showed up in a later scene. Jules did not appear to be good at computers. Lukas freaked out when Jules asked him to access the hard-drive and they parted ways back in episode 8. So who helped hacked the cameras just in time for Jules to escape?

Could it be Sim's wife since she moved over to IT? That would be incredibly convenient if Sim's wife not only allowed Jules to escape when she gained the upper hand, but was adept enough in IT to hack Judiciary's cameras to aid her escape. Especially considering Jules had just invaded her home, threatened her at gunpoint and cuffed her.

Was there anyone else that I might have missed in that episode that could have hacked the cameras?

Comment: I think they were just destroyed - likely Jules threw stuff at them.

Comment: @Mithoron, I re-watched that scene again and I think you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading @Mithoron's comment, I re-watched the scene where the monitors started going dark in the control room. There was a close-up of a monitor showing some object coming fast at the screen from below just before going dark. Therefore I  think it's very likely that Jules knew where the cameras were and destroyed them from below, out of the cameras' view. Thank you @Mithoron for answering my question.